# How to Iterate key value pairs in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this:
var test = "oldsite1: newsite1, oldsite2: newsite2";

I want to iterate over this to get the values.
I know I can convert to a string array like this:
var myArray = test.split(",");

but then I get the whole of the string up to the "," and I want to extract "oldsite1" and "newsite1".

Help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split again each array item and get the key as the first element and the value as the second

```js
var test = "oldsite1: newsite1, oldsite2: newsite2";
var items= test.split(',');

items.forEach(function(item) {
  var keyValue = item.split(":")
  console.log("this is the key: " + keyValue[0]);
  console.log("this is the value: " + keyValue[1]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `split` to convert the string to an array and then you can use array methods to manipulate.

```js
var test = "oldsite1: newsite1, oldsite2: newsite2";
var split = test.split(',');

split.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
})

console.log(split) //outputs an array of key values
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input format is close enough to valid JSON that I'd take it the rest of the way and then use `JSON.parse` to turn it into a javascript object. (Though if you can have your data in JSON in the first place, that'd be preferable...)

```js
var test = "oldsite1: newsite1, oldsite2: newsite2"

// wrap field names in quotes, and put curlies around the whole thing:
test = '{"'+ test.replace(/([:,]) /g, '"$1 "') + '"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(test);

// Now you can use obj as a regular old hash table:
console.log("All keys are ", Object.keys(obj));
console.log("oldsite1's value is ", obj.oldsite1);
// and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You may combine [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert your string into an array of objects:

```js
var test = "oldsite1: newsite1, oldsite2: newsite2";
testArr = test.split(',').map(function(ele, idx){
    var arr = ele.split(':');

    var retVal = {};

    retVal[arr[0]] = arr[1].trim();
    return retVal;
});

console.log(testArr);

testArr.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    var keyName = Object.keys(ele)[0];
    var keyValue = ele[keyName];
    console.log('keyName: ' + keyName + ' keyValue: ' + keyValue);
})
```